# Sharing the containers and images between ctr and docker

Tags: docker, containerd

The running container displayed in output of `docker ps -a` could be seen in the output of `ctr -n moby container ls`. This container was created by the docker engine and one can view it in the same namespace (moby) with ctr CLI. I tried doing vice versa meaning - running a container using ctr CLI and checking if it is present in docker ps output. Result? Didn't find it.

Similar experiment was tried with the images as well, the image pull from ctr was not reflecting in the docker images output.

Is there a way I can use ctr commands to reflect the results in docker system output?

PS I tried giving `moby` namespace in ctr commands, tried giving `rootfs` as runc root in ctr command.